# Get response from Artisan call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When I run in terminal `php artisan migrate` this results in 'Nothing to migrate' when indeed there is nothing to migrate.

When I use `Artisan::call('migrate')` in code (use this in a custom Artisan command) this doesn't return any message. It just executes the code without any feedback.

If I `vardump()` the result of the `Artisan::call` method it just returns an `int(0)`

Is it possible to get the response of the Artisan call method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The return result of all commands is defined in the class `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command`, method `run`:

```
return is_numeric($statusCode) ? (int) $statusCode : 0;
```

The `$statusCode` variable is set by calling the command's `execute` method, which in artisan's case is defined in the class `Illuminate\Console\Command`:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    return $this->fire();
}
```

The result of the `fire` method is left up to the individual commands, in the case of `php artisan migrate` command, nothing is returned from the method so the `$statusCode` is null (which is why you get the 0 returned from `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run` method)

If you want to get a response back from a custom command, just return an integer back from your `fire` method and it will bubble back up into the `$statusCode`.  You can use that to programmatically switch against different results of your custom command.

If you specifically want to get the result from the `artisan:migrate` command, then I don't think there's much you can do to change the return value besides wrapping the command in your own custom command that calls it.

Comment: The reason why `Symfony` does this is the way `Unix` and `Unix`-like systems work. If a command returns 0, it means it was successful, while if it returns any other number, it means it failed, and the specific number corresponds to a status code that may or may not be part of its public API. I'm not sure what is supposed to happen if the response is not an integer, but I think either the behavior is undefined or the system is supposed to behave as if the command returned 0.

Comment: @trysis If you will return string or array, the result will be `0`

Answer (score 24):

For me with Laravel 5.1 all this did not work but you can simply use:

```
Artisan::output()
```

Comment: note that this will only catch the output if u used `Artisan::run('')` just b4 it, other wise u get an empty output, its not a catch all command output

Answer (score 13):

I'm able to get the output of Artisan::call() with the via the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput;

$stream = fopen("php://output", "w");
Artisan::call("migrate", array(), new StreamOutput($stream));

var_dump($stream);
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible.  To get the output of a built-in artisan command from inside a custom command, pass the `OutputStream` from your command into the `Artisan::call`.  Example:

```
class MyCommand extends \Illuminate\Console\Command
{
    public function fire()
    {
        \Artisan::call('optimize', [], $this->getOutput());
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgive my apparent ignorance of PHP, but what is the backslash before the artisan call for?

Comment: @trysis: The backslash fully qualifies the [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php). `Artisan` is in the global namespace: `MyCommand` may not be.

Answer (score 2):

Late but might be of use to someone searching for the use case.

Let me add how i did it in my tests to print the results to console. my problem was printing output while tests are running migrations. i was using modules and wanted to see the results of the migration process.

```
$this->artisan('module:migrate');
//same as running php artisan module:migrate or
// $this->app['Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel']->call('module:migrate');

echo $this->app['Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel']->output();
```

Comment: This is actully the only answer that made sense and worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

When the Artisan command output you want is issuing an `echo`.

You can access this type of output with [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and [ob_get_clean](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php).

For example, if your command echos JSON.

```
Artisan::command('myecho:command', function () {

    echo json_encode(config('myconfig'), true);

})->describe('outputs json');
```

Then you can access the JSON output by wrapping the command call in a buffer:

```
\ob_start();
\Artisan::call('myecho:command');
$output = \ob_get_clean();

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will save some time to someone in the future, for me worked a mix of 2 answers:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput;

$stream = fopen("php://output", "w");
Artisan::call('migrate', [
    '--path' => 'database/migrations/customer',
    '--force' => true,
    '--database' => $connectionName
], new StreamOutput($stream));

$callResponse = ob_get_clean();
```

StreamOutput helps to put the response in buffer and ob functions to get the response.

Comment: Worked when I put ob_start(); before the fopen - laravel 10