# Get response of custom artisan command in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have created custom artisan command and trying to get response of it.
Here is the handle method of custom artisan command.

```
 /**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function handle()
{
    return 'Hello world';
}
```

Calling command from the controller

```
$result = Artisan::output('app:custom-command');
dd($result); // 0
dd(Artisan::output()); // ''
```

Expecting 'Hello world' in the controller.

> Please note I want response not the output

i.e Not the output of `$this->info('test.');`

Comment: Commands can only return an integer return status. That's a limitation for most operating systems I'm aware of so I would expect laravel to coerce any return value to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Commands don't  return spesific variable they return an exit code.
if you get "hello world" from command;

command:

```
$this->info('Hello World');
```

controller:

```
Artisan::call('app:custom-command');
return Artisan::output();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am aware of this and as mentioned is the question expecting response and the output.

Comment: hmm there is no way returning value of a command. only exit code returns

Answer (score 0):

First, please check these answers here:
[Get response from Artisan call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485513/get-response-from-artisan-call)

Just to give you an insight, here a small thing you can do:

1. You can pass a variable by reference to the constructor of the Command class

As an example:

```
// File => UserController
$commandInstance = new DemoCommand($output);
$commandInstance->hanlde(); // Calling the related method manually

// Then in the DemoCommand Class @constructur method
public function __construct(&$output){
 $this->output = $output;
}

// File => DemoCommand @handle Method
$result = ['a', 'b' ]; // ... 
$commandInstance->setOutput($result);
```

2. You can also use session, Redis to save the data in memory and read it from the related class you need or store the output into a file or database...